# Getting incorrect sort order

Tags: java, priority-queue

Failing test case:

- Input:
  [-2147483648,1,1]
- Output:
  -2147483648
- Expected:
  1

Why is the output expected as 1 when -2147483648 is the 2nd max number here?

```
public int thirdMax(int[] nums) {

    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue(new Comparator<Integer>(){
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b){return b-a;}
    });

    int res=0;

    for(int num : nums){
        if(!pq.contains(num)  )
            pq.add(num);

    }

    if(pq.size()<=2){
       for(int i=0; i<pq.size(); i++){
            res=pq.poll();
        }             
    }
    else {
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            res=pq.poll();
        }        
    }
    return res;   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of comparing isn't correct for `int`.

Rather than:

```
return b - a;
```

you should do:

```
return Integer.compare(b, a);
```

An `int` can only hold values of up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. But if you do `1 - -2147483648`, the result is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which makes it negative again - and you get wrong sort orders as a result. Basically, `return b - a;` is only safe if you know that all numbers are positive (or if the numbers won't be further apart than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`).

In other cases, you can use the API method `Integer.compare`.

Note that, since you are comparing by the inverse of the natural order of integers, you can also shorten your code with:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```